# Least squares estimation of a shift in linear processes by Bai(1994). Does it have to be stationary?

Tags: time-series, arima, econometrics, structural-change

So in his [paper](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/32878/1/MPRA_paper_32878.pdf)  **Least squares estimation of a shift in linear processes.**([Link](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/32878/1/MPRA_paper_32878.pdf)) Bai shows a method to find a structural break point in time series data. He states that to obtain the LS estimator for the breakpoint $\hat{k}$ given by $\hat{k}=agrmin_k(min_{\mu_1,\mu_2}\{\sum^k_{t=1}(Y_t-\mu_1)^2+\sum^T_{t=k+1}(Y_t-\mu_2)^2\}$ (3)
where $\mu_1$ is the mean of Y from t=0 to the breakpoint k and $\mu_2$ is the mean from breakpoint to the end. He then states that the equation (3) can be written as $\hat{k}=argmin_k(S^2_k)$.

He further adds $\sum^T_{t=0}(Y_t-\overline{Y})=S_k^2+V_k^2$  (4),

where $V_k=({k(T-k)\over{T}})^{1\over{2}}(\overline{Y}_k^*-\overline{Y}_k)\space where \space \mu_1=\overline{Y}_k \space and \space \mu_2=\overline{Y}_k^*  $.

Note that: $\hat{k}=argmin_k(S_k^2)=argmax_k(V^2_k)$

He then concludes that

> As will be seen, the statistical properties of the change point estimator are obtained
> by studying the behavior of $V_k$ and the argmax functional.

Then there is the part I do not understand.
I am confused because he states that the residuals are $\hat{X}_t=Y_t-\hat{\mu_1}-(\hat{\mu_2}-\hat{\mu_1})I(t>\hat{k})$, where $X_t$ is a stationary process. Does this mean that the data I am searching the break point for, needs to be stationary? But that does not make sense to me, as stationarity seems irrelevant to solve the minimization problem. And if I were to differentiate the time series to get stationary data, wouldn't that skew my breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then there is the part I do not understand...he states that the
> residuals are
> $\hat{X}_t=Y_t-\hat{\mu_1}-(\hat{\mu_2}-\hat{\mu_1})I(t>\hat{k})$
> where $X_t$ is a stationary process...

The stationarity (or not) of $X_t$ does not enter the definition of $\hat{X}_t$ in any way.

> Does this mean that the data I am searching the break point for, needs
> to be stationary?

The data series $Y_t$ is by definition not stationary---in particular, it's has a structural break in the mean $\mu$ and therefore not mean-stationary. The error term $X_t$ is stationary (in the strict or weak sense, depending on assumptions on p2).

Comment: Ok thanks, for making it clear. I do have a follow up question though. Also on **page 16** Bai says that the change point is defined by equation (3) but is estimated by maximizing equation (4) $V_k^2$. But why is that so? I thought one could use those interchangeably. So shouldn't you be able to either maximize $V_k^2$ or minimize $S_k^2$, because of $\hat{k}=minS_k^2=maxV_k^2$?

Comment: @Argonaut $\hat{k} = \arg\min S^2_k =  \arg\max V^2_k$. The minimizers are the same but the objective functions $S_k^2$ and $V_k^2$ are not the same. One would expect the $V^2_k$ formulation to be more convenient for deriving asymptotic distribution of the estimate.